# How to show or filter by qualifier?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

See eg. [P297 at Q37024](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q37024#P297), there are a qualifier (P582).

### Show/debug

This query is wrong, how to show the endtime's like the Q37024 case?

```
SELECT ?item ?iso2_code ?endtime 
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P297 ?iso2_code
  OPTIONAL { ?iso2_code pq:P582 ?endtime }
}
```

### Filter

I need all items that has no endtime.

---

### Notes about real case

I am querying

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?iso2_code  ?wd_id
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P297 ?iso2_code
  BIND(strafter(STR(?item),"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/") as ?wd_id).
} ORDER BY ?iso2_code
```

but retriving duplicates,

- AI        | {Q25228,Q1450765} | Q1450765 use P582, Q25228 not
- CS        | {Q33946,Q37024} ...
- DK        | {Q35,Q756617}
- GE        | {Q230,Q1050859}
- NL        | {Q55,Q29999}
- PS        | {Q219060,Q407199}
- YU        | {Q83286,Q838261}

so I need to exclude one, but the correct one: by endtime.

---

PS: there are a handbook about [WIKIDATA Qualifiers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Qualifiers,_References_and_Ranks) but with no real case of retrieving datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT (?simple_value AS ?iso2_code) ?wd_id
WHERE {
  ?item p:P297 ?statement .
  ?statement ps:P297 ?simple_value .
  # ?statement a wikibase:BestRank
  OPTIONAL { ?statement pq:P582 ?qualifier . }
  FILTER ( !bound(?qualifier) )
  BIND ( strafter(str(?item), str(wd:)) AS ?wd_id ).
} ORDER BY ?iso2_code
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%28%3Fsimple_value%20AS%20%3Fiso2_code%29%20%3Fwd_id%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP297%20%3Fstatement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP297%20%3Fsimple_value%20.%0A%20%20%23%20%3Fstatement%20a%20wikibase%3ABestRank%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3Fqualifier%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20%21bound%28%3Fqualifier%29%20%29%0A%20%20BIND%20%28%20strafter%28str%28%3Fitem%29%2C%20str%28wd%3A%29%29%20AS%20%3Fwd_id%20%29.%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fiso2_code%20)

You can use `FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?statement pq:P582 ?qualifier . }` instead   of
`OPTIONAL { ?statement pq:P582 ?qualifier . } FILTER ( !bound(?qualifier) )`.

Wikidata data model is documented [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format). There are many query examples on [this page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples), e. g. [this one](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#List_of_countries_by_age_of_the_head_of_government).